# Xcode retrieve userInfo from NSNotification

Tags: xcode, substring, nsnotificationcenter

I've an aNotification with a userInfo I'd like to call in another method with a different format.
Is there a way to retrieve a string from the [aNotification userInfo] and modify it?
userInfo is something formatted like this:
     {
    action = "the string I'd like to use";
}
I did like this (and it's almost working) but I feel there is a better way to do the same.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playClicked:) name:kNotificationActionTapped object:nil];    

 ..................

-(void)playClicked:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
NSLog(@"Notification=%@", [aNotification userInfo]);

SBJsonWriter *jsonWriter = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];

NSString *jsonString = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:[aNotification userInfo]];

[jsonWriter release];

NSString * string1 =  [jsonString substringFromIndex:11];
NSString * string2 = [string1 substringToIndex:[watch length] -2];


NSLog(@"string=%@", string1);
NSLog(@"string=%@", string2);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`userInfo` is an NSDictionary. Use standard NSDictionary methods.

```
NSString *aString = [aNotification.userInfo objectForKey:@"action"];
```